# Is there a way to get IShellBrowser from a dialog?

Tags: c++, shell, delphi, mfc, dialog

I know that windows common dialog have a IShellBrowser interface and its class name is 'SHELLDLL_DefView'. Refer [this](http://www.cnblogs.com/pangpangxiong/archive/2009/05/15/1457740.html).

How to get the IShellBrowser interface of a file open dialog?
(The file open dialog is outside's, not my application's.)

[This](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.asp?ArtID=1189389) is the same as my question but is delphi(?) ver.
I don't know delphi code. How to solve this problem as C++ or MFC code?

Comment: The Delphi code is only two lines. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why do you need the `IShellBrowser` of a file open dialog in the first place?  What are you planning on doing with it?  You don't own someone else's dialog, so why are you going to mess around with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C/C++ translation of the Delphi code:

```
const UINT CWM_GETISHELLBROWSER = WM_USER + 7;
IShellBrowser *ShellBrowser = (IShellBrowser*) SendMessage(aDialog, CWM_GETISHELLBROWSER, 0, 0);
if (ShellBrowser) {
    ShellBrowser->AddRef();
    // use ShellBrowser as needed... 
    ShellBrowser->Release();
}
```

You might also want to read the following article, which provides a slightly more official (ie, more reliable, but more complicated) way to get an `IShellBrowser` for a given `HWND`:

[Querying information from an Explorer window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393)

> Start with [the ShellWindows object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/shell/reference/objects/shellwindows/shellwindows.asp) which represents all the open shell windows. You can enumerate through them all with [the Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/shell/reference/objects/shellwindows/item.asp)... From each item, we can ask it for its window handle and see if it's the one we want... Okay, now that we have found the folder via its `IWebBrowserApp`, we need to get to the top shell browser. This is done by querying for the `SID_STopLevelBrowser` service and asking for [the `IShellBrowser` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/shell/reference/ifaces/IShellBrowser/IShellBrowser.asp).

Comment: IShellWindows can find just explorer windows, doesn't it?

Comment: @Empty: "*which represents **all the open shell windows**.*"

Comment: open shell windows is what is mean? File open dialog belong to Shell windows? I currently using the code in the post  'Querying information from an Explorer Window'. And I had tested the code but It can find just currently open explorer window, not find the currently open common file open dialog.

Comment: @Empty: The file dialog itself, no.  The Explorer window that is embedded inside of it as a child, yes.

Comment: @Empty: ask Microsoft, it is their dialog.  In the meantime, I ask you again, have you explored [Raymond Chen's other approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393) at all? You are focusing on an **undocumented** feature, when there is another **supported** solution available.

Comment: I read the post 'Querying information from an Explorer window' at all but I can't find a information about the way for getting file open dialog's IShellBrowser interface.

Comment: Then you did not read it carefully enough, particularly the section about "*From each item, we can ask it for its window handle and see if it's the one we want*".  Iterate the open shell windows, retrieving each HWND and comparing it to the dialog you are interested in until you find a match.